# bzr update! Is it able to update only part of the branch?

Tags: bazaar

I have a branch in local, eg. `~/project`

I only want to update the sub-directory `~/project/subdir1` and ignore all the other directory in `~/project`.

How could I do that?

Answer (score 0):

A simple update using bazaar will update the whole branch, not only a folder.

Maybe **NestedTreesDesign** can answer you question.

> 2   Basic approach
>
> Commands in containing trees should behave as though the subtrees were
>   plain directories. Commands in subtrees should not affect the
>   containing trees (except possibly with user intervention).

http://wiki.bazaar.canonical.com/NestedTreesDesign

Answer (score 0):

You can use views (see "bzr view") to only check out part of the branch on disk, in the working tree.

However, even with views, Bazaar will retrieve the full history for the tree - even if that history isn't going to be necessary for the working tree. In other words, this will not improve the size of the .bzr/ directory; it will reduce the size of the working tree in general.